# understanding Keras pool2d

Tags: keras

I have the code below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Reshape
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer, InputSpec

print K.image_data_format()
x = np.ones((1, 2, 2, 1))
x[0][0][0][0]=2
n = 2
squared = K.square(x)
print K.eval(squared)

pooled = K.pool2d(squared, (n, n), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", pool_mode="avg")
print K.eval(pooled)
```

And here is the result of pooled:

```
[[[[1.75]
   [1.  ]]

  [[1.  ]
   [1.  ]]]]
```

I understood average pooling but I do not know why the result is like that. Can someone please explain the result to me?
I used Keras with tensorflow backend and my image data format is 'channels_last'

Thank you.

Comment: You make the question unnecessarily complex. Why do you go through the steps of using `K.square(x)` when you can just do `x[0, 0, 0, 0] = 4` directly? Please make your question clearer and more minimal. It will be easier for anyone to help you.

Comment: ah, actually this code is just a part of big code. I just copy a piece to run and understand how it work. Tks.